# Getting "SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" on my API request

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Basically I've made a "simple" API called observations, using laravel 7 and Vue.js, my GET request is working but i can't do my DELETE and POST request, i have to say that i'm still learning Laravel so there might be a lot of mistakes.

little comment here: DELETE actually works (it deletes), it just don't reload all observations as it should be expected

Here is my vuecomponent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="card card-header">
            <h2> observaciones </h2><small> para futuras donaciones </small>
        </div>

        <div class="card card-body" v-for="observation in observations" v-bind:key="observation.id">
            <h4> {{observation.name}}</h4>
            <p> {{observation.content}}</p>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" @click="deleteObservation(observation.id)"> Borrar </button>
        </div>
        <!-- FORMULARIO PARA AGREGAR OBSERVACION -->
        <div class="card card-footer">
            <form @submit.prevent="addObservation">
                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre" v-model="observation.name">
                </div> -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea type="text" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="algun texto" v-model="observation.content">

                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Agregar observacion </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                observations:[],
                observation:{
                    id:'',
                    name:'',
                    content:''
                }
            }
        },

        created(){
            this.fetchObservations();
        },

        methods:{
            fetchObservations(){
                fetch('api/observations')
                .then(res=> res.json())
                .then(data=>{
                    this.observations= data;
                    console.log(data);
                });
            },

            deleteObservation(id){
                if(confirm('¿Estas Seguro?')){
                    fetch('api/observations/+id',{
                        method:'delete'
                    })
                    .then(res=> res.json()) // aca estaria el error
                    .then((data)=>{
                        fetchObservations();
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
                }
            },

            addObservation(){

                fetch('api/observations',{
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify(this.observation),
                    headers: {
                        'content-type':'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(res=> res.json())
                .then(data=>{
                    this.observation.content=''
                    alert("agregado")
                })
                .catch(err=> console.log(err));
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is my apicontroller:

```
class ObservationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $observation = Observation::all();
        return $observation;
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        // ESTO ES LO QUE FALLA
        $observation = new Observation();
        $observation->name = auth()->name();
        $observation->content = $request->input('content');

        $observation->save();

        return $observation; // borrar esto despues
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Observation  $observation
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
        $observation = Observation::findOrFail($id);
        $observation->delete();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Observation model

```
class Observation extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'content'];
}
```

and routes:

```
<?php

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('observations', 'ObservationController@index');

Route::post('observations', 'ObservationController@store');

Route::delete('observations/{id}', 'ObservationController@destroy');
```

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you `return null;` in your `destroy` method, so in your front end when you are trying to parse it to json it throws an error.

Try this.

```
            deleteObservation(id){
                if(confirm('¿Estas Seguro?')){
                    fetch('api/observations/+id',{
                        method:'delete'
                    })
                    .then(()=>{
                        fetchObservations();
                    })
                    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked perfectly fine, now im up to just the addObservation issue

Comment: @MartinAguirreFittipaldi consider accepting my answer?